# Долгая прорисовка изображений в pictureBox'ах

Tags: c#, winforms

Размер формы растягивается под разрешение экрана. 
На форме расположены следующие элементы:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox6;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox7;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox8;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox9;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox4;
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
```

При открытии формы, в неё сразу же загружаются изображения в панель из папки. Пример:

```
pictureBox2.Load("bgr/1.png");
```

**Изображения загружаются и показываются, но они долго прорисовываются, т.е. видно саму прорисовку изображения по частям.**

[Изображение 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ruSb.jpg)

[Изображение 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esOHA.jpg)

***Вопрос: как можно решить проблему долгой прорисовки изображений или сделать её незаметной для пользователя?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена путём удаления компонента `panel`, на котором находились `pictureBox`.

Comment: вы бы хоть в вопросе дописали, кто в кого вложен был исходно. Дополнил свой ответ расшифровкой вашего решения.

Answer (score 5):

1. Заранее загрузите изображения в программу. Обращение к диску - операция относительно долгая. Можно выполнить загрузку изображений перед открытием основного окна программы, секундная задержка при запуске будет не так заметна, как моргание элементов на форме. Можете также разместить изображения в ресурсах, тогда процесс загрузки за вас выполнит CLR, при загрузке сборки. Правда сборка может изрядно потяжелеть, если изображения большие.
2. Как уже предложили - включите двойную буферизацию. И идем дальше.
3. Масштабирование изображения в GDI+, да и в принципе - операция дорогая, поэтому, по возможности, заранее подготовьте изображения нужного размера.
4. Используйте `Control.SuspendLayout` перед обновлением изображений и `Control.ResumeLayout` после. Это заморозит визуальное состояние контрола или формы на время обновления контента, что опять же лучше моргания при перерисовке.

---

5. Расшифровка решения автора.

У базовых контейнеров двойная буферизация отключена и недоступна для настройки, данное свойство `Control.DoubleBuffered` имеет уровень доступа protected. Поэтому при размещении элементов со сложной отрисовкой или большими изображениями, что по сути одно и тоже, наблюдается видимое мерцание при обновлении контента. Тоже касается `PictureBox`.

Простое решение (см. ответ автора) - вынести проблемные контролы из контейнера прямо на форму. Но такой вариант не всегда применим, и в дальнейшем может вызвать ряд проблем при добавлении новых функций в приложение.

Более правильное решение - создание кастомного контрола унаследованного от подходящего по функционалу контейнера или `PictureBox`. В конструкторе включаем двойную буферизацию и используем этот контрол вместо стандартного. Собственно кроме настройки буферизации, можно ничего нового в код унаследованного контрола не добавлять, если в этом нет необходимости. Также можно добавить публичное свойство, позволяющее управлять буферизацией снаружи, как у формы.

Comment: Спасибо за расшифровку

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить свойство формы `DoubleBuffered=True`. Если не поможет, нужно запустить заставку перед загрузкой формы.

Comment: Свойство немного ускоряет прорисовку, но всё равно её видно. И желательно без заставки как-то это реализовать

Comment: Скорее всего изображения слышком большого размера, попробуйте их уменьшить.

Comment: такая же прогрузка будет, если убрать из из пикчербоксов картинки вообще